# Can you use ASIO input and a different output?

Tags: daw, asio

Can you set a DAW to use ASIO input and something else (laptop speakers for example) as the output?

Comment: I have seen many people asking how to combine their PC’s internal speakers and ASIO. I made this as an easy way to provide them with information.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not currently possible to use ASIO in a DAW as an input source, only, without using it as the output on Windows.

However, I have seen people claim [ASIO4ALL](https://www.sweetwater.com/sweetcare/articles/installing-and-using-asio4all-for-windows/) let’s you mix devices in some DAWs.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on Mac OSX but not on Windows. ASIO is limited to one device only, whereas on OSX you can create "aggregate or Multi-Out" virtual devices which you can then configure within your DAW.

Answer (score 2):

On the Microsoft Windows, you can use [ASIO4ALL](http://www.asio4all.org/) to use an audio output that is different from the audio input. For example, in the following screenshot, ASIO4ALL is configured to use the Focusrite USB as input, and the Virtual Audio Cable as output:

[image]

Note that you have to check the device (e.g., "Virtual Audio Cable") in addition to the the in
 (or out) checkboxes for it to be enabled:

[image]

Also, it seems that one can only use 1 output at once (e.g., one can't send the output to both the "Virtual Audio Cable" and the speaker). To be confirmed.