# Where can I view the latency caused by an effect in Adobe Audition?

Tags: effects, adobe-audition, latency

Where can I view the latency caused by an effect in Adobe Audition?

[image]

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/TWGu9a
- https://forums.adobe.com/message/11102648#11102648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible to view the latency caused by an effect in Adobe Audition.

From https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2620840 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190601234237/https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2620840)):

> There's no direct way to view latency, I'm afraid. The main reason for
>   this is that the amount of it is determined largely by the computing
>   power you've got, and this would mean having to make an external
>   measurement from input to output that's essentially independent of the
>   computer you're using. This is a bit tricky...
>
> So yes, you could measure system latency using external equipment, but
>   there's no way for the thing causing it to measure what it's actually
>   doing, if you see what I mean.